# How to use firebase query with a route resolver

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic4

I'm implementing a route resolver but I'm having type issues and I'm not sure how to resolve.

I'm navigating to a Group page like a social media group and I want to resolve the Group Data before routing to the page so I'm using a resolver.

```js
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<IGroup> {
        const groupId = route.paramMap.get('id');
        const test = this.groupDataService.getMyGroup(groupId);
        return test;
    }
```

The problem is that my `groupDateService` is returning a document reference.

```js
  getMyGroup(id) {
    const userGroup: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference = firebase.firestore().doc(`groups/${id}`);
    return  userGroup.get();
  }
```

I'm not sure how to make these types match.  When the `groupDataService` returns the document I need it to be of type `IGroup`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.